# using the {php} tags in smarty outputs a blank page

Tags: php, smarty

I have no experience in Smarty, Im trying to modify a `.tpl` file from a software not made by made, I am just added the `{php} {/php}` tags in a `.tpl` file with no code inside them at all, and its outputs seems a blankpage. First I had some code but it was outputting a blank page so I started to remove lines and now there are no lines at all inside the `{php} {/php}` tags yet it does that behaviour. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Smarty are you using? The PHP tag was deprecated a while back, and as of 3.1. can only be used with the backwards compatibility wrapper.

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.php.tpl

It's best if possible to keep your php in a separate class or controller (that way it's accessible to other templates as well), but if you really need to include it on the page, just include the smartybc class, as it says here: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/bc.tpl

```
<?php
// instead of
require_once('path/to/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php');
$smarty = new Smarty();

// use 
require_once('path/to/smarty/libs/SmartyBC.class.php');
$smarty = new SmartyBC();
?>
```

Also, if you'd like to see PHP errors (it's really annoying that you just get a blank page when something goes wrong, makes it hard to debug) you can activate debug mode by going to config/config.inc.php and finding the following lines and changing 'off' to 'on' for the first one and set to true the second

```
/* Debug only */
@ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
define('_PS_DEBUG_SQL_', true);
```

And that should display PHP and SQL errors for you.

Comment: Thanks! As I said before, I need to edit a software not made by me which uses Smarty. For what I see in one of the codefiles, it seems to be version 3.1 . And I just need a header.tpl file to perform a php code, even when it's good to read all the documentation of Smarty, I need to do this just one thing now and I probably would read it later considering how many open sources softwares use Smarty

Comment: Yeah, definitely turn on debugging then, hopefully that will help you sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using {php} tags, as they are described as deprecated in [Smarty docs](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.php.tpl). 
If you want some code to be ran, try preparing plugins for smarty as described [here](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins).